# NSURLSessionDelegate methods not called

Tags: swift

I'm trying to accept a self-signed SSL certificate and want to take the approach of using a delegate method on URLSession. Unfortunately the delegate method is never called:

```
func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, didReceive challenge: URLAuthenticationChallenge, completionHandler: (URLSession.AuthChallengeDisposition, URLCredential?) -> Void) {
    completionHandler(URLSession.AuthChallengeDisposition.useCredential, URLCredential(trust: challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust!))
}
```

I thought it might be this function, but

```
func urlSessionDidFinishEvents(forBackgroundURLSession session: URLSession) {
    print ("finish")
}
```

is also not called.

I set up a single-view project and pushed to Git to show the issue

https://github.com/stevencurtis/selfsigned.git

But here is the code in that single-view:

```
import UIKit
```

class ViewController: UIViewController, URLSessionDelegate {

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    getRequest()
}

func getRequest() {
    let request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://example.com")!)
    let session = URLSession(configuration: .default, delegate: self, delegateQueue: .main)
    let dataTask = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest)
    dataTask.resume()
}



func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, didReceive challenge: URLAuthenticationChallenge, completionHandler: (URLSession.AuthChallengeDisposition, URLCredential?) -> Void) {
    completionHandler(URLSession.AuthChallengeDisposition.useCredential, URLCredential(trust: challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust!))
}

func urlSessionDidFinishEvents(forBackgroundURLSession session: URLSession) {
    print ("finish")
}

func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, dataTask: URLSessionDataTask, didReceive response: URLResponse, completionHandler: (URLSession.ResponseDisposition) -> Void) {
    // We've got the response headers from the server.
    print("didReceive response")
    completionHandler(URLSession.ResponseDisposition.allow)
}

func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, didBecomeInvalidWithError error: Error?) {
    // We've got an error
    if let err = error {
        print("Error: \(err.localizedDescription)")
    } else {
        print("Error. Giving up")
    }
}
```

}

So how can I get these delegate methods to be called?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the protocol based **or** the block based API but not both simultaneously.

The simple reason is that the block based API doesn’t set the required delegate.

If you need the delegate methods use only the [protocol based API](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlsession/1411597-init).

---

Side note:

Do not use `NSMutable...` classes if there is a native Swift equivalent. `URLRequest` is mutable as `var`iable.

Comment: I've updated to set the delegate as self, but it still does not call the methods.

Comment: You must not use `dataTask(with` with the completion handlers and you have to create the session with the (linked) designated initializer.

Comment: Which initializer is the designated one?

Comment: What alternative is there to dataTask?

Comment: Use `dataTask(with` without completion handler. Please read the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlsession).